# How to eliminate the through-line from a legend element in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble eliminating a black through-line from an element in my legend. The black line is in the "% of Hires by Casual Users" element.

Below is my code, followed by a link to the output plot

EDIT - please note that I've added code to reproduce the problem elsewhere. This data is random and the output will not look the same as the visual below. However, it returns the same problem and can be used with the original code.

```
Account.type <- c("Casual", "Member", "Casual", "Member", "Casual", "Member", "Casual", "Member", "Casual", "Member")
how <- c(0, 10, 25, 35, 50, 60, 75, 100, 125, 150)
hire <- c(4540, 6780, 9125, 1000, 6993, 5435, 2347, 0693, 5434, 5432)
cas_percent <- c(34, 65, 54, 12, 65, 78, 89, 76, 54, 43)
plot_data <- data.frame(Account.type, how, hire, cas_percent)


    #plot x (time)
    plot <- ggplot(data = plot_data,
                   aes(x = how)) 

    #plot percent casuals
    plot <- plot + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = (cas_percent), fill = "% of Hires by Casual Users"), colour = "transparent", alpha = .5, show.legend = TRUE) 

    #plot hires 
    plot <- plot + geom_line(aes(y = hire/100, colour = Account.type), size = .8, show.legend = T)

    #fill aes 
    plot <- plot +   scale_fill_manual(name = '',  values=c("% of Hires by Casual Users" = "grey")) 

    #visualise
    plot

    #add title
    plot <- plot + labs(
      title = "Who Uses the Twin City Bike Share?", 
      y = "Hires (100's)",
      x = "Day of Week")

    #adjust x axis 
    plot <- plot + scale_x_continuous(
      breaks = c(0, 24, 48, 72, 96, 120, 144),
      label = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")) + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=-0.05))

    #adjust right y axis
    plot <- plot + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1, name = "Percent of Hires by Casual Users [%]"))

    #visualise
    plot
```

Output: 
[image]

Any suggestions on how I fix the legend?

Comment: Please provide reproducible data.

Comment: Remove `show.legend = TRUE` from the `geom_point` layer?

Comment: geom_ribbon? tried it and didn't work. Thank you

Comment: @DanielPatterson Remove show.legend = TRUE from both layers

Comment: That did the trick - thank you @dmi3kno and aosmith

Comment: I will add the solution. Please upvote and accept

Answer (score 0):

You can use `guide_legend` to change `linetype` and set it 0.

Change below line

```
plot <- plot + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = (cas_percent),
fill = "% of Hires by Casual Users"), 
colour = "transparent", alpha = .5, show.legend = TRUE)
```

as

```
 plot <- plot + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0, 
    ymax = (cas_percent), fill = "% of Hires by Casual Users"),
    colour = "transparent", 
    alpha = .5, 
    show_guide = TRUE) + 
    guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0)))
```

should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `show.legend=TRUE` from both layers. Your plot should read:

```
ggplot(data = plot_data, aes(x = how)) +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = (cas_percent), fill = "% of Hires by Casual Users"), 
                colour = "transparent", alpha = .5) +
geom_line(aes(y = hire/100, colour = Account.type), size = .8) +
scale_fill_manual(name = '',  values=c("% of Hires by Casual Users" = "grey"))
```

[image]